# Office Web Apps Server 2013 - OpenFromURLEnabled deactivate

Tags: office-web-apps

I found the folowing command for the Office Web Apps Server and this command works great:

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -OpenFromURLEnabled
```

But how can I deactivate OpenFromURL?

Delete an recreate is a option for sure. 
but is there also a command to deactivate OpenFromURL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219442.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, says it is a switch operator. So it should just be a matter of running the command like this `Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -OpenFromUrlEnabled:$false` based on their examples.